# How do I enable auto-merge on a github pull request via the Rest API

Tags: github, github-api

I have permission, the repo allows it. I create a bunch of PRs using a cli tool and then I have to go open N tabs and double click the Enable Auto-Merge -> Confirm process for each one.

Does the API offer an issue/pr modify method to set this attribute automatically without resorting to the UI?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it like this:
Request POST to https://api.github.com/graphql to get pullRequestID value
body:

```
query MyQuery {
    repository(name: "repo-example", owner: "org-example) {
        pullRequest(number: 49) {
                  id
              }
        } 
}
```

With pullRequest ID make a mutation:
Request POST to https://api.github.com/graphql

```
mutation MyMutation {
    enablePullRequestAutoMerge(input: {pullRequestId: "$pullRequestID", mergeMethod: MERGE}) {
        clientMutationId
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that at the moment it's not possible to do it via Rest API, but you can use GraphQL API mutation [`enablePullRequestAutoMerge`](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations#enablepullrequestautomerge)  instead.

Answer (score -2):

It is now possible to do it through the REST API:

```bash
curl -L \
  -X PATCH \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO \
  -d '{"allow_auto_merge":true}'
```

See: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos?apiVersion=2022-11-28#update-a-repository

Comment: This enables it on the repository, not on the pull request.